# Getting a few Windows Phone properties for instrumentation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm interested in:

1. User's Cell Network
2. User's Connection Type (Wifi, 3G, Edge, etc)
3. User's City

Are these accessible via standard Windows Phone APIs (v7.0 SDK)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get the User's City you will need to use the Location Services on the phone to get the current location and perform your own reverse geocoding.

If you do this, be aware you will need to make sure you meet Marketplace requirements for use of the Location Services before publish your app. Especially if you send out the location data from the phone to a 3rd party lookup service.